# calculating clustering validity of k-means using rapidminer

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means, rapidminer

Well, I have been studying up on the different algorithms used for clustering like k-means, k-mediods etc and I was trying to run the algorithms and analyze their performance on the leaf dataset right here:
http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Leaf

I was able to cluster the dataset via k-means by first reading the csv file, filtering out unneeded attributes and applying k-means on it. The problem that I am facing here that I wish to calculate measures such as entropy, precision, recall and f-measure for the model developed via k-means. Is there an operator avialable that allows me to do this so that I can quantitatively compare the different clustering algorithms available on rapid-miner?

P.S I know about performance operators like Performance(Classification) that allows me to calculate precision and recall for a model but I dont know any that allow me to calculate entropy.

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is to use R. Here's a [link](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=X2_OBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA159&lpg=PA159&dq=Visualising%20Clustering%20Validity%20Measures&source=bl&ots=DOYntiWiQX&sig=gQDxrrUfZugo6DooSZT8k5vR_1E&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi31_fJ4bnMAhVHBMAKHfMRCokQ6AEIMjAD#v=onepage&q=Visualising%20Clustering%20Validity%20Measures&f=false) to a book chapter about this very subject. There is a revised version coming soon that works for the most recent version of RapidMiner.

Comment: R, or sklearn, or ELKI, or ... any programming-friendly tool will do.